# I can't position a div where I want it to go

Tags: css

my html is

```
    <h1> Website </h1> 
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
            <li><a href="about.html"> About</a> </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My css is

```
#menu {
   margin: 0;
   padding: .3em 0 .3em 0;
   background: #ddeebb;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
}
```

I want my list to appear at the top right of the page. Its for a navigation bar. But instead of displaying on  top of the navigation bar, they display underneath it on the left. I dont know if this is an issue, but instead of making any css or html for a navigation bar, I just edited my webpage background to have a horizontal bar across the image and im trying to position the links on top of it.

Comment: Can you share some image representation of how you want to place?

Comment: in your css it should be #menu not menu

Comment: `float:` is ignored if you're using `position: absolute`. It looks like you're employing cargo-cult programming to solve the problem rather than understanding exactly what each property expression does.

Comment: http://imgur.com/jv8mr1S
here's an image. 
The links appear below. I want them to be on the right side of the grey bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this what you looking for?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: green;
            right: 1em;
            top: 1em;
            padding:.3em;
        }
        #menu ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding:.3em 3em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Website </h1> 
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your menu is inside another div which doesn't allow your menu to go top right it wouldn't go where you want
you can either edit your parent div or use css inside `menu { }`

```
position:absolute;
left: Xpx;
top: Xpx;

X=integer number of pixels
```

you will have to add number of pixels on width inside menu or in your body
if you type width:100% in a div and its parent doesn't have something like width:500px then your div will have width as much it needs to appear content next to each other

Answer (score 0):

If you want your menu to "float" on the right side of your page you can use this code:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1> Website </h1>
```

with this CSS:

```
#menu {
   margin: 0;
   padding: .3em 0;
   background: #ddeebb;
   float: right;
}
```